# CheckBox invertidas c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Tenho este código.

Está-me a ler as checkbox de cima para baixo, quando elas tiverem todas selecionadas. Mas o que eu precisava era, quando ele começasse a ler, queria que ele começasse a ler do 2.9.15 para cima. E não do 2.9.16 para baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
foreach (UltraListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
    if (item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        DataTable versionToUpdateDT = mUpdater.GetVersionToUpdate((int)item.Tag);
        mVersionSelect = item.Text;
    }    
}
```

Não sei se isso é possível.

Comment: Ana, você quer que, por exemplo, ao marcar o `CheckBox` **2.9.15.1** todos acima dele sejam marcados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível, mas não usando `foreach`. Neste caso, use o comando `for`:

```
for (int x = listView.Items.Count-1; x >= 0; x--)
{
     UltraListViewItem item = listView.Items[x];
     // aqui continua o seu código
}
```

Comment: tentei fazer isso e aparece esta mensagem :O índice estava fora do intervalo. Tem de ser não negativo e inferior ao tamanho da colecção.\r\nNome do parâmetro: index"}

Comment: @AnaCarvalho, atualizei o código, faltou -1 no `count`

Comment: Já consegui. Muito obrigada :)